# Mock HTTPSession

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, httpsession

**I use jdk1.6.0_24, when I try to mock HTTP session with Mockito I have the next error:**

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: javax/servlet/http/HttpSession : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.(TestClass.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.(ParentRunner.java:75)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)

**When I use JDK 1.7 it works, but in my project I must use JDK 1.6, how can I solve this problem?**

Comment: I must use JDK 1.7 or JDK 1.6 ?

Answer (score 1):

You've compiled your classes under JDK 1.7, but then you are running under older version of JDK 1.6.

This is the meaning of *java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError* exception

Answer (score 1):

You will have to compile the classes again in 1.6 and run it again. It will work. Currently what you have done is compile the classes in 1.7 and run in 1.6